# Error "Failed to compare two elements in the array - At least one object must implement IComparable" for delete multiple row in EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

I use EF Core 3.1 and this is my code:

```
public async Task DeleteSessions(List<Guid> ids)
{
    var sessions = new List<Session>();
    foreach (var sessionId in ids)
    {
        var session = await _dbContext.Sessions.FindAsync(sessionId);
        sessions.Add(session);
    }

    _dbContext.Sessions.RemoveRange(sessions);

    // error occurred on this line
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

But exception throw on SaveChagedAsync with this error

> Failed to compare two elements in the array - At least one object must
> implement IComparable

Also I changed my code to this:

```
public async Task DeleteSessions(List<Guid> ids)
{
     foreach (var sessionId in ids)
     {
          var session = await _dbContext.Sessions.FindAsync(sessionId);
          _dbContext.Sessions.Remove(session);
     }

     // error occurred on this line
     await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
 }
```

But does not matter and exception throw on `SaveChagedAsync` method again

If I delete one by one and call `SaveChangedAsync` the method work correctly, but I need to delete multiple row in one transaction.

Why EF Core doesn't support multiple row deleting? and how can resolve this problem?

**More Information:**

```
    public class Session
    {
        public BusinessId Id { get; private set; }

        public string Title { get; private set; }

        public DateTime StartDate { get; private set; }

        public int ExtraDurationAsMinute { get; private set; }

        public string LatestServerId { get; private set; }

        public Courses.Course Course { get; private set; }

        private Session()
        {
        }

        public static async Task<Session> Create(Guid sessionId, Courses.Course course, DateTime startDate, string title)
        {
            var session = new Session
            {
                Id = sessionId,
                Course = course
            };

            session.ChangeStartDate(startDate);
            session.ChangeTitle(title);

            return session;
        }

        public void ChangeServer(string serverId)
        {
            this.LatestServerId = serverId;
        }

        public void ChangeTitle(string title)
        {
            if (Title == title)
            {
                return;
            }

            this.Title = title;
        }

        public void ChangeStartDate(DateTime startDate)
        {
            if (StartDate == startDate)
            {
                return;
            }

            this.StartDate = startDate;

            Course.CalculateFirstAndLastSession();
        }

        public void ChangeExtraDuration(int duration)
        {
            if (ExtraDurationAsMinute == duration)
            {
                return;
            }

            ExtraDurationAsMinute = duration;

            Course.CalculateFirstAndLastSession();
        }

    }
```

This is EF Sessions configurations:

```
public class SessionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Core.DomainModels.Sessions.Session>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Core.DomainModels.Sessions.Session> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(x => x.Id)
                .HasConversion(x => x.Value,
                    x => BusinessId.FromGuid(x));

            builder.Property(x => x.LatestServerId).HasMaxLength(100);

            builder.HasOne(x => x.Course);
        }
    }
```

This is exception stack trace:

```
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Array.Sort[T](T[] array, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Sort(Int32 index, Int32 count, IComparer`1 comparer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.CommandBatchPreparer.<BatchCommands>d__11.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<SaveChangesAsync>d__97.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<SaveChangesAsync>d__101.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.<SaveChangesAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SilverPath.Infra.Data.Sql.Commands.BaseEntityFrameworkUnitOfWork`1.<CommitAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in O:\Projects\SpAzure\Elearno-Reborn\Institute\Develop\Framework\SilverPath.Infra.Data.Sql.Commands\BaseEntityFrameworkUnitOfWork.cs:line 32
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at ElearnoInstitute.Core.ApplicationServices.Sessions.Command.SaveSessions.SaveSessionHandler.<Handle>d__2.MoveNext() in O:\Projects\SpAzure\Elearno-Reborn\Institute\Develop\Institute\src\Core\ElearnoInstitute.Core.ApplicationServices\Sessions\Command\SaveSessions\SaveSessionHandler.cs:line 83
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SilverPath.Framework.EndPoints.Web.Controllers.BaseApiController.<Execute>d__11`1.MoveNext() in O:\Projects\SpAzure\Elearno-Reborn\Institute\Develop\Framework\SilverPath.EndPoints.Web\Controllers\BaseApiController.cs:line 66
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at ElearnoInstitute.Endpoint.ClientApi.Controllers.V1.SessionController.<SaveSession>d__3.MoveNext() in O:\Projects\SpAzure\Elearno-Reborn\Institute\Develop\Institute\src\Endpoint\ElearnoInstitute.Endpoint.ClientApi\Controllers\V1\SessionController.cs:line 85
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.<Execute>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at SilverPath.Framework.EndPoints.Web.Middlewares.ApiExceptionHandler.ApiExceptionMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext() in O:\Develop\Framework\EndPoints.Web\Middlewares\ApiExceptionHandler\ApiExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 35
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but your parameter should not be a list of IDs but should rather be a set of some kind.

Comment: `RemoveRange` accept IEnumerable<> and List<> inherent for IEnumerable. So does not matter.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I encourage clear semantics

Comment: Very strange. So `Find` is working, but you get exception on `SaveChanges`m correct? Can we see the model (`Session` class, configuration, PK, related entities)? Also the exception stack trace?

Comment: I added some more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ef needs a deterministic order when updating rows because if there are two threads updating the same rows and the order is reversed it might result in a deadlock
see this [SaveChanges() deadlocks](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/6666)

so

```
BusinessId should implement IComparable<BusinessId>
```

your problem will be solved :)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with the **MAUI Blazor app**. And I ended up here. I think that my solution will be useful for applicants like me

I found the solution in this article
https://www.koskila.net/how-to-fix-your-maui-blazor-app-crashing-on-startup-with-failed-to-compare-two-elements-in-the-array/

> Solution
> Check your routes for duplicates. It’s a bit annoying you don’t get a proper error message, but you can just ctrl+shift+f “@Page” in Visual Studio to get a list of all Page-directives, which are probably the likeliest way to set a route to cause duplicates (since you set them per-component).

> I have no idea where my duplicate route had appeared (I mean, who would copy-paste a component with routes from the internet?), but since my app was small, it was easy enough to spot the duplicates.

> That said, if your @Page directives are fine, take a look at your MauiProgram.cs or Program.cs to see if you’re issuing some conflicting directives there.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. There are probably hundreds of ways to get the same .net exception. That doesn't mean they all apply to this question.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but that's why I clarified. It's for seekers like me. Let me explain for you. Having my problem, I immediately came here. Therefore, it will be useful for applicants like me. And for them, this is a poor solution to a problem like mine.

Comment: That's what people always say. On Stack Overflow we answer questions, not only titles. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion, esp. "Always solve the asker's problem." If you think this is really really useful you can ask a question and self-answer it. Note that it should be a question that meets the usual Stack Overflow standards.

Comment: I'm outraged that you gave me a negative rating, because it matters to me. Especially when I did everything within the community rules. I suggest you read the rules first, before you refer to "help/promotion". 

"Answer for the ages. If you want folks to view your work positively, write with an eye toward answering not just the asker's problem but also the problems likely to be had by those finding the question in the future. In particular, always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works..."

Comment: I used that link because it clearly states "Always solve the asker's problem.". That always applies, regardless of the title of the link. Note that there are many questions on Stack Overflow that have this same problem: the title contains a generic exception message, slowly but surely leading to (sometimes) tens of answers having no bearing on the question in hand. Finding a fitting answer there is virtually impossible. The same thing will happen here. The issue here is related to a very specific EF feature (value conversions). Please let people find answers to *that* issue here.

Comment: If you don't agree, please bring it to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/